# Put two buttons side by side

Tags: css

I have this code and finally figured out how to make the buttons sit side by side, but now I can't figure out how to make a space between them.  They also sit with a very large margin between the buttons and the top of the page.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>


<style type="text/css">
    .classname {
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #4fa3f7), color-stop(1, #378de5) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #4fa3f7 5%, #378de5 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4fa3f7', endColorstr='#378de5');
background-color:#4fa3f7;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:20px;
border-top-left-radius:20px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:20px;
border-top-right-radius:20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:20px;
border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:20px;
border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
text-indent:0;
border:1px solid #84bbf3;
    display:inline;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
height:65px;
line-height:65px;
width:131px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #528ecc;
    float: left;

}


.classname:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5),             color-       stop(1, #4fa3f7) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #378de5 5%, #4fa3f7 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',                    endColorstr='#4fa3f7');
    background-color:#378de5;
}.classname:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;



div.button{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 7px;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><center><h3>Where would you like to stay?</h3></center></p>

<div class="button"> 
<a href="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/where-to-stay-north-padre/" class="classname"><font        color=white>North Padre</font></a> 

<a href="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/where-to-stay-port-aransas/" class="classname"><font      color=white>Port Aransas</font></a>

<a href="http://www.padreislandbeach.com/where-to-stay-south-padre/" class="classname"><font color=white>South Padre</font></a>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many things wrong with your code.  Here are a few tips to make your life easier (all the changes I made can be seen at https://www.diffchecker.com/mydyojpc):

- `.classname` should be a descriptive classname.  I changed it to `.button`.
- `float:left` was messing up your code.  I removed it so you could center your buttons, and add many other CSS properties.
- The reason your hover gradient didn't work was because you had a space between `color-stop`.  It looked like `color-` `stop`.
- You had multiple CSS values that are discontinued (not used anymore).  I replaced them with updated properties.
- You had *so many `border-radius-top-left` etc.* properties that could be shortened with the `border-radius` shorthand.  Basically I removed all those lines of code and replaced it with 3 lines that did the exact same thing.

### http://jsfiddle.net/67m3gq9s/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should also put `white-space: nowrap;` inside `.button{}`, if not it would cut like this: http://i.imgur.com/aF6NoD3.png

Answer (score 0):

Your actual buttons are `.classname`, not `.button`. Therefore, you need to apply the margins to your anchors.

```
a.classname {
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

I also noticed a few deprecated tags that you shouldn't use (not altogether with modern css3 features, at least).
`<font>` and `<center>` are deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Do you try with `margin` ?

```
.classname{
  margin-left:10px; 
}
```